# Database operation in sandbox web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i need to insert record in my database using sandbox web part.

can anyone please give me some detail how can i do this.

because if i used sql command operation in sandbox it give me wrapper error.

Comment: Sandboxed webparts don't exist in SharePoint 2007.  Are you using SharePoint 2010, and just mis tagged your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the SandBox Proxy, check it here "How to: Create and Register a Sandbox Proxy" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx#Y1353